# Fancybox not display the entire contents of the iframe until I scroll down

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, fancybox-2

I have a page in an iframe and inside the iframe are commanded to call the fancybox , everything works fine except for google chrome . It seems as if not finished loading the contents of fancybox or as transparent until I scroll in any direction .

Someone has this happened ?

```
if (typeof(bkg_fb_img) != "undefined") {

  $.fancybox({
    'padding': 0,
    'transitionIn': 'elastic',
    'transitionOut': 'elastic',
    'href': numhtml + '.html',
    'type': 'iframe',
    'iframe': {
      scrolling: 'no',
      preload: true
    },
    'opacity': false,
    'nextSpeed': 0, //important
    'prevSpeed': 0, //important
    'keys': {
      close: [27]
    },
    helpers: {
      overlay: {
        css: {
          'background': 'url(' + bkg_fb_img + ') no-repeat 0 0 scroll',
          'background-size': '100% 100%',
          'overflow': 'auto'
        },
        closeClick: function() {
          redEnv()
        }
      }
    },
    'afterClose': function() {
      redEnv()
      if (typeof(tiempo) != "undefined") {
        counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);
      }
    }
  });
} else {
  $.fancybox({
    'padding': 0,
    'transitionIn': 'elastic',
    'transitionOut': 'elastic',
    'href': numhtml + '.html',
    'type': 'iframe',
    'nextSpeed': 0, //important
    'prevSpeed': 0, //important
    'keys': {
      close: [27]
    },
    'opacity': false,
    helpers: {
      overlay: {
        closeClick: function() {
          redEnv()
        }
      }
    },
    'afterClose': function() {
      redEnv()
      if (typeof(tiempo) != "undefined") {
        counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the code that is failing so we can help you better?

Comment: Looks good.  Hope you get an answer soon.

Comment: are you wrapping your fancybox initialization code in the `.ready()` method?

Comment: No, initialize each time command to call some function, but after a lot of testing there seems to details when used within an iframe and position the iframe this after half parent page, because if I put in the top has no problem.